# Eclipse: How to change the "Find/Replace" Search Highlight Colors?

Tags: eclipse, search, colors

**CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)**

**Eclipse Version:** 2020-06 (4.16.0)   **Build id:** 20200615-1200

When I use the dialog box invoked by Ctrl F ( command: Find and Replace ) I get the search results highlighted in a faint yellow.

This makes it very hard for me to see the result.

**I dutifully went to Google** and found that the highlighted search result color can be changed by going to:

**Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > Search Results**

Interestingly, when I got there the highlight color was not yellow.  It was a light blue.

Still, I changed the color to red,hit apply, apply and close, and restarted Eclipse.

No change.

Any ideas what I can to get that color to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the ***Selection background color*** that can be changed in *Window > **Preferences: General > Editors > Text Editors***:

[image]

Comment: That was it!  Thank you.